# assigning files in a directory to sub-directories

Tags: linux, bash

I have a 1000s of files in a directory with and I want to be able to divide them into sub-directories, with each sub-directory containing a specific number of files. I don't care what files go into what directories, just as long as each contain a specific number. All the file names have a common ending (e.g. .txt) but what goes before varies.

Anyone know an easy way to do this.

Comment: `Anyone know how an easy way to do this.` -- Maybe you could talk about a not-so-easy way to begin with?

Comment: manually mv a specific number of files into each sub-directory would be one not-so-easy way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you only have files ending in `*.txt`, no hidden files and no directories:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob

maxf=42

files=( *.txt )

for ((i=0;maxf*i<${#files[@]};++i)); do
    s=subdir$i
    mkdir -p "$s"
    mv -t "$s" -- "${files[@]:i*maxf:maxf}"
done
```

This will create directories `subdirX` with `X` an integer starting from 0, and will put 42 files in each directory.

You can tweak the thing to have padded zeroes for `X`:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

files=( *.txt )
maxf=42
((l=${#files[@]}/maxf))
p=${#l}

for ((i=0;maxf*i<${#files[@]};++i)); do
    printf -v s "subdir%0${p}d" "$i"
    mkdir -p "$s"
    mv -t "$s" -- "${files[@]:i*maxf:maxf}"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
max_per_subdir=1000
start=1
while [ -e $(printf %03d $start) ]; do
  start=$((start + 1))
done
find -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name '.*' -name '*.txt' -print0 \
| xargs -0 -n $max_per_subdir echo \
| while read -a files; do
  subdir=$(printf %03d $start)
  mkdir $subdir || exit 1
  mv "${files[@]}" $subdir/ || exit 1
  start=$((start + 1))
done
```

Comment: Oh dear, this doesn't work for filenames containing spaces or funny symbols!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: I know it doesn't work with whitespace, but what funny symbols would break it?

Comment: newlines and tabs or more generally everything in `IFS`.

Comment: Is defending against IFS set to more than whitespace really within the scope of this question?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
find *.txt -print0 | xargs -0 -n 100 | xargs -I {} echo cp {} '$(md5sum <<< "{}")' | sh
```

This will create several directories each containing 100 files. The name of each created directory is a md5 hash of the filenames it contains.

Comment: This fails in many ways with file names containing spaces or funny symbols.

Comment: Yes not meant for production. Meant to address the 'easy way' part of the OP's question.